# Improve image quality to read blurry numbers by OpenCV

Tags: image, opencv

I have an image (in very low quality): [image]

I was wondering if there is any suggestions help me improve quality so I can read numbers plate on that image (not 100% but much as possible) by OpenCV?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since I am not able to comment I can suggest an answer here.

First if all, you should use a noise removal filter as [median filter](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga564869aa33e58769b4469101aac458f9&gsc.tab=0), followed by a [laplacian filter](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga564869aa33e58769b4469101aac458f9&gsc.tab=0) or [Canny](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga564869aa33e58769b4469101aac458f9&gsc.tab=0) or any edge detection filter to enhance the edges a little bit. You should choose convenient parameters for both filters. Remember, it is subjective from one person to another, so the parameters depends mainly on you.